# Applescript Excel Cell Search and Replace Other Cell

Tags: excel, macos, applescript

I'm a new user to apple script and am hoping for some assistance.

I am trying to use Applescript and Excel to automate my work so that it can go faster.

After going through an applescript to dedupe records, I want to be able to check a column (Column A) if it has a number value of more than 100. If yes, I would like another column (Column B) in the same row to be pasted with the text "Registered".

Following that I would like to autofilter and remove any row in which Column B has the text "Normal"

Thank you in advance for your help.

Below is the code I am using for removing columns and deducing records.

Updated Questions as of 11 Oct 2014
1) I need to select a row based in a cell in the last column that is in text. As long as the feel is not SG. the row should be selected
2) I need to be able to copy that row and move it to become the last row (this is a tough one because I see a never-ending cycle from this logic - will an end repeat stop this cycle?)
3) I need to remove all blanks from the list.
4) I need 1 and 2 to be done in sequence from top to bottom so that their IDs are not jumbled up.

Updated on 11 October 2014 with ShooTerko's script

```
tell application "Finder"
activate
open document file "orders.csv" of folder "Input" of folder "Automation" of folder "AAS Orders" of folder "A A Selections 1st June" of folder "Adlina A. Pte Ltd(NEW)" of folder "Fizzy Pop Pte Ltd" of folder "Dropbox (Fizzy Pop)" of folder "zayedtalib" of folder "Users" of startup disk

tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    tell active sheet of active workbook
        set myColumn to range "B:K"
        delete myColumn
        set myColumn to range "C:D"
        delete myColumn
        set myColumn to range "D:V"
        delete myColumn
        set myColumn to range "F:G"
        delete myColumn
        set myColumn to range "K:AA"
        delete myColumn
    end tell
end tell
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    set maxRow to count of rows of used range of active sheet
    repeat with currentRow from maxRow to 2 by -1

        set currVal to (value of row currentRow of column 1 of active sheet)

        set nextVal to (value of row (currentRow - 1) of column 1 of active sheet)

        if currVal = nextVal then
            delete range (row currentRow) of active sheet
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    autofilter range range "C:C" field "1" criteria1 "Normal >14days"
end tell
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    if exists active sheet then
        set usedRows to every row of (used range of active sheet) whose value is not missing value

        -- Walk through the used rows
        -- Set values of column B to "Registered" if value of column A is greater than 100
        repeat with aRow in usedRows
            if (value of row (first row index of aRow) of column ((first column index of aRow) + 1) is greater than 100) then
                set value of row (first row index of aRow) of column ((first column index of aRow) + 2) to "Registered"
            end if
        end repeat

        -- Loop from last rows to first rows to easily delete rows
        -- Delete all rows containing "Normal" in column B
        repeat with aRow in (reverse of usedRows)
            if (value of row (first row index of aRow) of column ((first column index of aRow) + 1) = "Normal") then
                delete aRow
            end if
        end repeat
    end if
end tell
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    autofilter range range "C:C" field "1" criteria1 "Registered"
end tell
```

end tell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this and it worked as described:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    if exists active sheet then
        set usedRows to every row of (used range of active sheet) whose value is not missing value

        -- Walk through the used rows
        -- Set values of column B to "Registered" if value of column A is greater than 100
        repeat with aRow in usedRows
            if (value of row (first row index of aRow) of column (first column index of aRow) is greater than 100) then
                set value of row (first row index of aRow) of column ((first column index of aRow) + 1) to "Registered"
            end if
        end repeat

        -- Loop from last rows to first rows to easily delete rows
        -- Delete all rows containing "Normal" in column B
        repeat with aRow in (reverse of usedRows)
            if (value of row (first row index of aRow) of column ((first column index of aRow) + 1) = "Normal") then
                delete aRow
            end if
        end repeat
    end if
end tell
```

Comment: Hi ShooTerko,

Thank you so much for your solution. 

Your suggestion definitely works. 

I've added the code as well as a few others in for my workflow and now I am missing the final piece as I have indicated in my updated question.

Hope you'll be able to assist.

I've updated my question